# Prove a metric space generated by a $\sigma$-field is complete

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, metric-spaces

The following question is from *Linear Operators* written by **Nelson Dunford** and **Jacob T. Schwartz**, Chapter III.7.1

Let $(S, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a positive measure space and $\Sigma$ (proper $\sigma$-algebra) will be defined as a field where the addition is the symmetric difference (denoted by $\Delta$) and multiplication the intersection (we just write $AB$ instead of $A\cap B$). Let $\mathcal{N}$ be the ideal of all $\mu$-null sets in $\Sigma$ and assign the quotient set $\Sigma/\mathcal{N}$ the following metric:

$$d(A, B) = \arctan\mu(A \Delta B)$$
Also, we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\begin{split}
&(AB)\Delta(A_1B_1)=[A(B\Delta B_1)]\Delta[B_1(A\Delta A_1]\\
&A^c\Delta A_1^c = A \Delta A_1\\
&(A \cup B)\Delta(A_1\cup B_1) = (A\Delta A_1)\Delta(B\Delta B_1)\Delta[A(B\Delta B_1)]\Delta[B_1(A\Delta A_1)]
\end{split}
\end{aligned}
$$

Then one can show operations $A \bigcup B, AB, A\Delta B, A^c$ are all (jointly) continuous.Now the question is to show that metric space $(\Sigma/\mathcal{N}, d)$ is complete.

Given $\{E_n\}$ where $\lim\sup d(E_n, E_m)=0$, my attempt is to use the fact that $L^1(S, \Sigma, \mu)$ is weakly complete, show $\chi_{E_n}$ converge to an $f \in L^1(S, \Sigma, \mu)$ weakly. Then show that $f$ is a characteristic function, say $\chi_E$. However, I do not know if $E \in \Sigma/\mathcal{N}$. Any hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints: If $\chi_{E_n} \to f$ in $L^{1}(\mu)$ then there is a subsequence $(\chi_{E_{n_k})}$ conveging to $f$ almost everywhere. Let $g(x)=\lim \chi_{E_{n_k}}(x)$ if the limit exists and $0$ otherwise. Then $g$ is measurbale and $f=g$ a.e.. Further, $g$ takes only the values $0$ and $1$ so it is $\chi_C$ where $C=\{x: g(x)=1\}$.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. My solution (inspied by yours) is to show that $\|\chi_{E_n}\chi_F - f\chi_F\|_1 \rightarrow 0$ for any $F \in \sigma$ and $\mu(F) < \infty$ so that we know $\chi_{E_n} \rightarrow f$ pointwise almost-everywhere. Is this how you conclude the pointwise convergence?

Comment: @SanaeKochiya $\chi_{E_n}$ converging to $f$in $L^{1}$ does not imply a.e. convergence. (There are standard counter-examples). But there is a theorem which says that there is subsequence which converges to $f$ a.e. Taking a subsequence is essential.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your idea and I wrote another solution based on measure convergence $\Longrightarrow$ pointwise convergence (a,e,). Please let me know if it it similar to the theorem you mentioned.

Comment: How do you say $g(x)$ is measurable?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{\epsilon_n\}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers and $\epsilon_n \overset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$. Supposed there is an $n \geq 1$ such that the set $S[(\chi_{E_k} - f), \epsilon_n] = \{s \in S\,\vert\,\vert\chi_{E_k}(s)-f(s)\,\vert > \epsilon_n\}$ has measure greater than $\epsilon_n$ for all $k \geq n$. For $k$ large enough such that $\int_S \vert\,\chi_{E_k}(s)-f(s)\,\vert\,\mu(ds) < \epsilon_n^2$ we obtain the contradiction. Hence we have for any $n \geq 1$ there is $k_n\geq n$ such that $\mu(S[(\chi_{E_{k_n}} - f), \epsilon_n]) \leq \epsilon_n$. Then $\chi_{E_{k_n}} \rightarrow f$ pointwise a.e.. The $\mu$-measure convergence further implies $f$ is $\mu$-measurable and hence a characteristic function of a set in $\Sigma$.